# Networking: Switch hopping versus Router to switch

Tags: networking, router, switch

I have a router with 1 WAN and 3 LAN ports and 2 switches with 8 ports, I'm wondering what's the pros and cons of setting them up as:

A) Router LAN1 to SWITCH-A and SWITCH-A connected to SWITCH-B.

versus

B) Router LAN1 to Switch-A and Router LAN2 to SWITCH-B

They are all 2.5gb ports on all ends, so I'm wondering if there are limitations or benefits to each solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Switches process millions of packets/sec - there is no cons AFAIK for this scenario, as the bottleneck would potentially be cables and long runs of cable, not the switches. Switches simply pass traffic from point A to point B and don't route traffic _(it's why they're often referred to as dumb switches)_. SU or google have some answers that can further elaborate on the differences between routers and switches that may be more informative

Comment: That's not exactly what I was asking for. I assume option A might be slightly better (although the bottleneck might be the same, 2.5gbe when switch A has to communicate with B) since switches are tailored for high traffic and I might leave the router bandwidth left for internet and not Intranet related activity.

Comment: It's exactly the same. Traffic goes through the router anyway - the switches are unaware of the IPs.

Comment: I believe that's incorrect, switches manage MAC address smartly enough to know where to deliver traffic without all of it going through the router (which in turn sets the communication rules for the network)

Comment: @Thi Since you're asking about a practical scenario you have the ability to test, it would likely provide you a far more accurate answer to simply use `iperf` to measure the transfer speeds between two hosts routed as in A and B, then compare. Generally, it seems like this would mainly be of concern within a business running multiple switches and routers with a large network versus a home network comprised of relatively short cable runs, however someone with more experience than I would have to fact check that